# confused about cheerio nextUntil

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I am trying to parse some html using cheerio, and for one set of tags cheerio.nextUntil() seems to work as expected, but for another set it doesn't

this is the code

```
(function () {
    const cheerio = require('cheerio');

    const html = `
        <h2>Reset spent time for an issue</h2>
        <p>Resets the total spent time for this issue to 0 seconds.</p>
        <pre><code>POST /projects/:id/issues/:issue_iid/reset_spent_time
        </code></pre>

        <h2>Get time tracking stats</h2>
        <pre><code>GET /projects/:id/issues/:issue_iid/time_stats
        </code></pre>`;


        let $ = cheerio.load(html);

        $('h2').each(function(index,element) {
            let name = $(this).text();
            let description = $(this).next('p').text();

            let url = $(this).nextUntil('pre').next('pre').text().trim();

            console.log({
                name,
                description,
                url
            });
        });
})();
```

the result I'm getting is

```
{ name: 'Reset spent time for an issue',
  description: 'Resets the total spent time for this issue to 0 seconds.',
  url: 'POST /projects/:id/issues/:issue_iid/reset_spent_time' }
{ name: 'Get time tracking stats', description: '', url: '' }
```

I expect the second `description` to be '', but don't understand why the second url is blank

if I change the code to

```
        let url = $(this).nextUntil('pre').next('pre').text().trim();
        let foo = $(this).next().text();

        console.log({
            name,
            description,
            url,
            foo
        });
```

I get

```
{ name: 'Get time tracking stats',
  description: '',
  url: '',
  foo: 'GET /projects/:id/issues/:issue_iid/time_stats\n        ' }
```

so, foo is what I expected

nextUntil() does this

> Gets all the following siblings up to but not including the element
>   matched by the selector, optionally filtered by another selector.

so, because it says "following siblings, but not the matched element" and the next sibling *is* the matched element, so it doesn't match it, and it's not included , then `next()` doesn't then work ?

if so, what mechanism could I use to get the desired result ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case, nextUntil is returning an empty set, so there's nothing to get "next" from.

You can add "addBack" to your call to make sure you always have an object.

```
let url = $(this).nextUntil('pre').addBack().next('pre').text().trim();
```